# First derivative of solution to nonlinear diffusion-type equation

Tags: limits, partial-differential-equations

We know that the diffusion equation
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}$$
smooths out initial conditions $u(x,0)=g(x)$ before finally vanishing in the long-time limit. I was wondering for what other families of diffusion-type equations this is true. E.g., say I have the nonlinear diffusion-type equation
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=F\left(\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2}\right)$$
subject to the initial condition $u(x,0)=g(x),\ x\in\mathbb{R}$,
where $F$ and $g$ are some (simple) smooth functions. I now am interested in conditions such that
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=0,$$
so the solution becomes asymptotically flat (smooth) but does not necessarily vanish. Asking for an answer for any functional form of $F$ is hard, but assuming something like $F(x)=x^\alpha,\ \alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ is also fine. In particular, I don't even know how one would actually prove this is true in the case of normal diffusion, let alone how to start on the more general problem.

Comment: The types of PDE's that have the "smoothing" behavior you are interested in are elliptic PDEs. For more information see [here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/pdes/ch4.pdf)

Comment: are there also other choices for $F$ (appart from identity) for which you would have a "smooting" behavior you know of?

Comment: I don't think equations of the form $\partial_t\phi=(\partial_x^2\phi)^\alpha$ have been well studied, but those of the form $\partial_t\phi=\partial_x(\kappa(\phi)\partial_x\phi)$ have, see the references [here](https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/1811/1811.06337.pdf).

Comment: well, that's a bummer. But thanks for your help